# Cannot include "vcruntime_new_debug.h"

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, unreal-engine4

I am trying to compile the UE4 C++ project and I'm facing this error

```
Running D:/UE_4.24/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe Development Win64 -Project="F:/Unreal/MyProject11/MyProject11.uproject" -TargetType=Editor -Progress -NoHotReloadFromIDE
Creating makefile for MyProject11Editor (no existing makefile)
@progress push 5%
Parsing headers for MyProject11Editor
  Running UnrealHeaderTool "F:\Unreal\MyProject11\MyProject11.uproject" "F:\Unreal\MyProject11\Intermediate\Build\Win64\MyProject11Editor\Development\MyProject11Editor.uhtmanifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAsErrors -installed
Reflection code generated for MyProject11Editor in 12,6746457 seconds
@progress pop
Building MyProject11Editor...
Using Visual Studio 2017 14.16.27034 toolchain (D:\ProgramData\????? ?????\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023) and Windows 10.0.17763.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
Building 11 actions with 8 processes...
  @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 0%
  @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 9%
  [1/11] Default.rc2
  @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 18%
  [2/11] SharedPCH.Engine.ShadowErrors.cpp
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\new.h(13): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'vcruntime_new_debug.h': No such file or directory
```

I don't know what is vcruntime_new_debug.h.
I updated all the packages like a .NET framework or Visual C++ Redistributable.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find it either.
So I just download the header file from [Github](https://github.com/icestudent/vc-19-changes).
You may be missing other header files as well, so better copy the whole vcruntime *